# jQuery Masonry layout is breaking when window is resized — fluid seamless photo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, jquery-masonry, window-resize

I have posted a [video](http://test.davewhitley.com/not-wp/static_folder/bug.swf) explaining my problem.
Sorry for the slow frame rate.

When I shrink the window too fast, the Masonry jQuery plugin seems to be too slow to keep up and therefore breaks the layout when the browser is resized too quickly. Some of the items fall below the footer, and it looks obviously wrong.

When I reload the page, as seen in the video, the layout returns to normal.

I think it is a problem is `smartresize`

Here is the demo page:
http://test.davewhitley.com/not-wp/isotope_test/index.php

This page successfully does it:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/collective/collective-2/

the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var CollManag = (function() {
    var $ctCollContainer = $('#ct-coll-container'),
    collCnt = 1,
    init = function() {
        changeColCnt();
        initEvents();
        initPlugins();
    },
    changeColCnt = function() {
        var w_w = $(window).width();
        if( w_w <= 600 ) n = 2;
        else if( w_w <= 768 ) n = 3;
        else n = 4;
    },
    initEvents = function() {
        $(window).on( 'smartresize.CollManag', function( event ) {
            changeColCnt();
        });
    },
    initPlugins = function() {
        $ctCollContainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $ctCollContainer.masonry({
                itemSelector : '.ct-coll-item',
                columnWidth : function( containerWidth ) {
                    return containerWidth / n;
                },
                isAnimated : true,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 300
                }
            });
        });
        $ctCollContainer.colladjust();
        $ctCollContainer.find('div.ct-coll-item-multi').collslider();
    };
    return { init: init };
})();
CollManag.init();
});
```

Comment: How did you fix this in the end? I noticed the site is live now so assume you've fixed it? I have exactly the same problem, would love to know what you did to get it working??

Comment: www.davewhitley.com just uses CSS to create the fluid grid of thumbnails since all of the images are square. I ditched the javascript approach just to keep it simple. My test site that I linked above mostly works, but when you resize the window, the images fall below the footer sometimes. If you come up with a solution, please post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great work by the way.

At certain points, yes, the layout goes a little crazy. Surely this is just down to the way browsers handle percentage widths + masonry. Great little tip below:

Make your container smaller, but your images larger.

.mycontainer { width: 24%; )
.mycontainer img { width: 101%; height: auto; )

http://metafizzy.co/blog/beyonce-seamless-fluid-image-masonry/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I used `bindResize` on windows resize. I found this solution on their website

[**Masonry Methods**](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html)

`bindResize` is at [**masonry.pkgd**](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/dist/masonry.pkgd.js)

```
$container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.container'
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $container.masonry('bindResize')
});
```

Comment: For anyone still looking for an answer, the easier way would be to just destroy the current instance and reinitialize the masonry. It helped me. Precisely, use the '.destroy' function on current instance and then reinitialize the same way you setup your masonry!